# Name array with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an add button that uses a directive to add-to a table's (.estimates) tbody:

```
function EstimateCtrl( $scope, $compile ) {

    $scope.services = [
            { 'value': 'c', 'name': 'Standard Courier' },
            { 'value': 'xc', 'name': 'Express Courier' },
            { 'value': 'cc', 'name': 'Country Courier' }
    ]

    $scope.add = function() {

        angular.element('.estimates tbody').append( $compile('<tr estimate></tr>')($scope) );

    }

}

angular.module('dashboard', [])
    .directive('estimate', function() {

        return {

            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<td><input type="text" placeholder="Suburb"/></td><td><select ng-model="estimate.service" ng-options="service.value as service.name for service in services" class="form-control"></select></td><td>$0.00</td><td><button type="button" class="remove">x</button></td>',
            link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {

                element.find('.remove').bind('click', function() {

                    element.closest('tr').remove();

                });

            }

        }

    });
```

How can I have an element array using ng-model in angularjs? For example:

```
<select name="foo[]"></select>
```

to

```
<select ng-model="foo[]"></select>
```

I've been digging around for a day and half but I can't seem to catch a break. I was hoping that maybe someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you very much for any help.

---

**Edit:** Here is the link to the plunker I'm sure after seeing this everyone is going know what I'm on about:
[http://plnkr.co/edit/JlYB9P0vyAqghOmeNYh4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDDHZ.png)

---

**Edit2:** Let's see if I can give you all another example to show you what I'm after

```
<form method="POST" action="">

<!-- I was attempting to do ng-model="estimate.service[]" but of course this doesn't work -->
<select name="estimate[service][]">
    <option value="foor">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
<select name="estimate[service][]">
    <option value="foor">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
<select name="estimate[service][]">
    <option value="foor">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>

<?php

if ( $_POST )
{

    print_r( $_POST['estimate']['service'] );

}

?>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or a plunker?

Comment: Check out my complete solution and tell me if understood your problem correctly

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you're trying to achieve try the second edit :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ohrighty! I managed to find a work around.

I have abandoned directives and did it another way, here is my working code:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <table>
        <tbody ng-repeat="service in estimate.services">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Suburb"/></td>
                <td>
                    <select ng-model="estimate.services[service.name]" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options" class="form-control"></select>
                </td>
                <td>$0.00</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="remove">x</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function Ctrl( $scope, $compile ) {

    $scope.estimate.services = [
        { name: 'service1', value: '' }
    ];

    $scope.options = [
        { name: 'Option 1', value: 'opt1' },
        { name: 'Option 2', value: 'opt2' },
        { name: 'Option 3', value: 'opt3' }
    ];

    $scope.add = function() {

        $scope.estimate.services.push({
            name: 'service' + ($scope.estimate.services.length + 1),
            value: ''
        });

    };

}
```

Comment: Instead of "<select ng-model="estimate.services[service.name]", simply having "<select ng-model="service" would also work, much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

Ok lets say you have two arrays of configurable options:

```
options1=[...]
options2=[...]
```

Now if I understand correctly you want a select box that enables yout to select one set of them right? So first you need to enclose both of them in another array or as mentioned before another object.

So lets use an object (I can provide an array example as well)

```
var $scope.myOptions ={'LabelForOptions1' : options1, 'LabelForOptions2' : options2}
```

Next we need a place to store the options that were choosen

```
 $scope.selectedOptions = {};
```

and lastly the select box itself

```
<select ng-model="selectedOptions" ng-options="value as key for (key,value) in myOptions"></select>
```

Note that the options1 and options2 variable could be also a single value and the example would still work

**COMPLETE SOLUTION TO PROBLEM**:
I assume this is your model:

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.options1 = ['Foo1','Bar1'];
    $scope.options2 = ['Foo2','Bar2'];
    $scope.options3 = ['Foo3','Bar3'];
    $scope.allOptions = [$scope.options1, $scope.options2, $scope.options3];
    $scope.selectedOptions = ["none","none","none"];
};
```

So this would be the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/myAngular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">
<div><select ng-repeat="option_set in allOptions"ng-model="selectedOptions[$index]" ng-options="value for value in option_set">
</select></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qGRQF/11/

Comment: Think in terms of when you have several options but you want to have all their values under the same name so you use an element array `option[]` or `<input type="text" name="option[]"/>` so when you do something like `print_r( $_POST['option'] )` you are given all the options that had been entered. I'm horrible at explaining something so if it doesn't make any sense let me know and I'll try and re-phrase.