# How to get values of input in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular JS are created `inputs`.

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

How I can to get values from each inputs and send to server?

I tried:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="typeInput">
```

But I get value only one field.

In server I am planning to get data format: `$_POST['type'][0] = 'One value'; $_POST['type'][1] = 'Two value';`

I mean, that I need send to server array of values. For example:

```
name="type[]" value="1"
name="type[]" value="2"
name="type[]" value="3"
```

So, in server I cando loop for check:

```
foreach($_POST['type'] as $val){
  //prepare
}
```

Comment: use that ng-model as `$scope.typeInput` while sending it

Comment: Specify your question clearly. It does not specify what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the ng-model binds it to the property of the same name in the $scope of the controller.

You would access it in your controller like so:

```
$scope.typeInput
```

Or you can access it in your HTML like so:

```
{{typeInput}}
```

To access both fields, you would need to give them both a different property name to bind to.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
<input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
...
alert($scope.firstName);
alert($scope.lastName);
```

More complete info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Edit: Here's an example fiddle with binding your inputs to an array: https://jsfiddle.net/gxmw62rj/2/

Comment: But If I want to sent array of fields to server? How as like: `name="type[]"`?

Comment: The same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810730/angularjs-name-array-with-ng-model

Comment: @Hamed - I made an update to show binding to an array.